# How to send request to a website through POST request?

Tags: python, post, web-development-server

My purpose is to write a python script which returns the facebook ID when a url is given as input. I found this [website](http://findmyfbid.com/) which does the same thing.

I want to ask:

1) Is it possible that I send a POST request myself which will include the url entered by user using "urllib" library "urlopen" command? And then extract the answer from urllib.read() function?

2) If not possible, how can I do this task?

I have little idea about POST and HTTP. But can't figure this out.

From reading the page source, the POST request is being sent this way:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input
            name="url"
            type="text"
            placeholder="https://www.facebook.com/YourProfileName"
            class="input-lg form-control">
        </input>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Find numeric ID &rarr;</button>

</form>
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at python-requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for a much simpler way to do http requests from Python. And you __really__ need to learn how the HTTP protocol works if you expect to do anything web-related.

Comment: I know, I have that in mind, but can you pin point the arguments this website is sending and receiving this once? The received url contains the word success and the facebook id, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: What about reading the facebook-api documentation ?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the easiest answer would be for you to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)
you can install it using

```
pip install requests
```

the normal usage would be ( assuming you're using python 3) :

```
import requests
payload={
    'key1':'value1',
    'key2':'value2'
}
r = requests.post('http://url', data = payload)
print(r.content)
```

If you want to use urllib you can use this sample code found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii') # data should be bytes
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: The values being passed in this case are? (the facebook id website)